# private key use in android application

Tags: android, bash, google-cloud-platform

I use this line to authenticate into my google cloud virtual instance:

```
ssh -i private_key user@35.122.322.43
```

Then I enter the passphrase and I'm in the gc virtual instance's shell.

I need to authenticate into ip `35.122.322.43` in my android application, but it's not a secure solution to store private key in the android application.

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Credentials stored on the device are insecure -  better solution would be to use 0Auth ( and good news - google cloud supports it for sure, and there are android libraries to do this )

Comment: 0auth seems useful, thanks. There's one thing: If I login into my google account in the application, does that mean that I can run scripts on the account's google cloud virtual instance, so I don't need to include the private key in the app? Thanks